# How to concatenate multiple short parameters to a single string using bash?

Tags: bash, parameters, concatenation

I would like to concatenate multiple parameters to a single string in `bash` like this:

```
$ ls -latr
$ cp -Rv directory1 directory2
```

The best I can do is something like this:

```
while (( ${#} ))
do
    case "${1}" in
        "-h" | "--help")
            getScriptUsage
            exit 0
            ;;

        "-i" | "--include-alpha-builds")
            include_alpha_build_versions="true"
            ;;

        "-r" | "--redownload")
            removeAllFiles
            ;;

        "-t" | "--torbrowser-version")
            tarball_filename_version="${2}"
            shift
            ;;

        "-v" | "--version")
            getVersion
            ;;

        *)
            getScriptUsage
            /bin/echo -e "\e[01;31mParameter '${1}' not found.\e[0m"
            exit 1
    esac

    shift || break
done
```

[Source](https://codeberg.org/keks24/torbrowser-launcher-bash/src/branch/master/home/username/bin/torbrowser#L184)

But with that, I can only append the parameters:

```
$ torbrowser -i -r -t 9.5
```

Might be off topic: I also would like to be able to mix parameters around, like in `cp`:

```
$ cp directory1 directory2 -Rv
$ cp -Rv directory1 directory2
```

Comment: don't reinvent the wheel!  bash provides you getopts function

Comment: Agreed on `getopts`. Spend your time mastering that. Good luck.

Comment: Oh nice! I did not know that. I will have a look at this then. Thanks!